# java.io.FileNotFoundException: read.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)`

Tags: java, java-io, ioexception

I always get this error when I try to run it:

```
IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: read.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
    try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("read.txt"));
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("write.txt"))){
    String l;

    while((l=in.readLine())!=null)
     out.write(l);
   }
   catch(IOException e){System.out.println("IOException: "+e);}
```

**MORE** I am using Netbeans 8.0.1. I have gone through some similar queries on this site and  have tried placing the above mentioned read.txt along with the src folder, inside it as well as along with the class file. But I am still getting this error. Can someone please point out my mistake?

I have just noticed this when trying to build project. I am new so could not understand if it has something to do with my problem

```
ant -f "E:\\Programming\\Projects\\java files\\JavaNio1_3" -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: E:\Programming\Projects\java files\JavaNio1_3\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory E:\Programming\Projects\java files\JavaNio1_3\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: E:\Programming\Projects\java files\JavaNio1_3\build
Updating property file: E:\Programming\Projects\java files\JavaNio1_3\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: E:\Programming\Projects\java files\JavaNio1_3\build\classes
Created dir: E:\Programming\Projects\java files\JavaNio1_3\build\empty
Created dir: E:\Programming\Projects\java files\JavaNio1_3\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 1 source file to E:\Programming\Projects\java files\JavaNio1_3\build\classes
Copying 2 files to E:\Programming\Projects\java files\JavaNio1_3\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: E:\Programming\Projects\java files\JavaNio1_3\dist
Copying 1 file to E:\Programming\Projects\java files\JavaNio1_3\build
Nothing to copy.
Building jar: E:\Programming\Projects\java files\JavaNio1_3\dist\JavaNio1_3.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "E:\Programming\Projects\java files\JavaNio1_3\dist\JavaNio1_3.jar"
jar:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Can you clue us in on the structure of your project?  What is the exact location of `read.txt` ?

Comment: what is path of read.txt?

Comment: You code works fine if the read.txt file is in the same directory where you execute the code.

Comment: You could also use the absolute path the the file on your file system.

Comment: The `src` directory won't be there at runtime. Put it somewhere else.

Comment: Place your file in classpath and try clean build

Comment: Place your file in project main folder it will work. Otherwise create file with java and then check whether it is creating in project directory or somewhere else.

Comment: As everyone has already said...the code does work if you place the read.txt file directly into the project folder (not the src folder) but do me a favor...place the braces for your while/loop. NetBeans should have given a warning about that: while((l=in.readLine())!=null) { out.write(l); }

Comment: Thanks for the reply everyone. I have placed the file in the project folder but its still giving the same error.

Comment: yes I will definitely do that DevilsHnd. Thank you for that.

Comment: Add this code at the start. It will print the "default" directory for the VM:
       System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());

Comment: Thank you for your reply SlipperySeal. I did as you said and it gives out "E:\Programming\Projects\java files\JavaNio1_3\.". I have placed the read.txt file in the JavaNio1_3 folder itself. Its still giving me the exception.

Comment: The exception message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help. Finally solved!

I tried what **kakurala** had mentioned in the comments above and it worked!

"create file with java and then check whether it is creating in project directory or somewhere else. – kakurala"

thanks man..and thank you all for taking the time to answer.

This thread can be closed now :)

Answer (score 0):

Just read the details of exception its self explanatory [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html):

> A file with the specified pathname does not exist

That is `VM` does not find any file you are specifying in `FileReader`.

Your `read.txt` file should be in NetBeans project directory e.g.

```
C:\Users\ABC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Sample\read.txt
```

Sample code with test file in drive:

```
try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\MyTasks.txt"));
     BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("write.txt"))){
     String l;
     while((l=in.readLine())!=null)
         out.write(l);
     }
 catch(IOException e){System.out.println("IOException: "+e);}
```

Comment: Have already done that sarz. but its still giving me an exception.

Comment: Code updated this should work and verify location of write.txt